# How to access populated array in another sub in VBA, w/o arguments?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am so confused, and endless googling is so far defying me. 
I have a sub that collected unique values in Column C into an array. Now that the array is created, I need to use it in a different sub so I can loop through the values.

I have tried passing it as an argument but then I can't figure out how to run the new sub that has arguments, i.e.:

```
Sub useArray(ByRef varArr() As String)
```

- how in the world do I run useArray? And useArray should be the main sub, anyways, so I am just confused about how I could then run the main sub and use this array variable that has already been defined/populated.

I tried using my sub that gets the unique values as a function, but it doesn't pass the values in the array back to the main sub. At the end of the function AND in the main sub I have:

```
MsgBox varArr(1)
```

In the function, it returns the first value. Back in the sub it returns an error.

An assistance would save my sanity!

Comment: You could turn your sub into a function

Comment: I've always referred to Pearson's descriptions for arrays: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/passingandreturningarrays.htm

Comment: Can you edit the question to include more of your code? It isn't exactly clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred method is going to be turning your Sub into a Function:

```
Function useArray(ByRef varArr() As String) As string()

    varArr(2) = "changed it"
    useArray = varArr

End Function
```

Which you would call by:

```
Sub test()

    Dim a(2) As String

    a(0) = "a0"
    a(1) = "a1"
    a(2) = "a2"

    MsgBox useArray(a)(2)

End Sub
```

Comment: In Excel 2010 this won't compile.

Comment: @ArnovanBoven Strange that you're having issues... [I'm not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jigax.gif) (No clue what the green screen is about in the last frame though - I think it's the color used to detect unchanged pixels to make the file smaller).

Comment: Says 'Can't assign to array' on `useArray = varArr(2)` in Excel 2010

Comment: That's because it's `useArray = varArr` @ArnovanBoven - `useArray` hasn't been dimensionalized until you assign the array to it

Comment: Hahaha oh my - I see it now. Thanks!! @ArnovanBoven

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()
    Call DoSomethingWithArray(PopulateArray)
End Sub

Function PopulateArray() As Variant
    PopulateArray = Array("foo", "bar") ' return some array
End Function

Sub DoSomethingWithArray(ByVal someArray As Variant) ' process array
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(someArray) To UBound(someArray)
        Debug.Print someArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```